# How can I convert a variable from one collation to another?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a script that switches between two databases: master & 'B'.

Database master has collation 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'

Database B has collation 'Latin1_General_CI_AS'

I have tried using the COLLATE and CAST commands but to no avail so far.

```
USE B
DECLARE @ProductsUserName varchar(200)
SET @ProductsUserName = 'SomeValue'

USE master 
DECLARE @UserNameMaster varchar(200) = @ProductsUserName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
DECLARE @GrantViewServerStatement varchar(200) = 'GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO ' + @UserNameMaster
```

The Query will blow up on the last line and will give the error:

'Implicit conversion of varchar value to varchar cannot be performed because the collation of the value is unresolved due to a collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in add operator.'

Obviously there is some kind of problem using the '+' operator between two varchars that have different collations. But not sure how to "cast" the variable into the new collation!

Comment: Which DBMS you are using? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL? Please tag it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform the collation as part of the string concatenation. i.e.:

```
USE B
DECLARE @ProductsUserName varchar(200)
SET @ProductsUserName = 'SomeValue'

USE master 
DECLARE @UserNameMaster varchar(200) = @ProductsUserName
DECLARE @GrantViewServerStatement varchar(200) = 'GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO ' + (@UserNameMaster COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS)
```